# Query SQLite Database using Processing-Based Android App

Tags: android, sqlite, processing

I am trying to write a [Processing](https://processing.org/)-based Android app that needs to communication with a SQLite database. To do this, I am trying to use the [Ketai Library](http://ketai.org/examples/externalsqliteloading/), but I am having an issue with it: I cannot use the library because Processing complains about an indirect reference to `android.content.Context;`. Here is my code for the project.

```
import ketaisqlite.*;

KetaiSQLite database;

void setup()
{
  // Preliminary Stuff
  orientation(LANDSCAPE);
  lights();
  fullScreen(P3D);

  // Database Connection
  KetaiSQLite.load(this, "/sdcard/Android/database.sqlite", "database");
}
```

Here are the two messages in the Error Console.

```
The type android.content.Context cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files The type android.content.Context cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
The method load(Context, String, String) from the type KetaiSQLite refers to the missing type Context   The method load(Context, String, String) from the type KetaiSQLite refers to the missing type Context
```

Trying to add `import android.context.Context;` creates an additional problem:

```
Only a type can be imported. android.context.Context resolves to a package  Only a type can be imported. android.context.Context resolves to a package
```

What do I do? I have looked at the [code for the library](https://github.com/ketai/ketai) itself and cannot figure out what is wrong with it, if anything.

Answer (score -1):

Add a new tab to processing called "required.java". The name isn't important, but it seems that processing Android needs a .java file to work with imports.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11018779)

Comment: @ndn Why is this not an attempt to answer the question?